# This query replace to Laravel. How to write in laravel?

Tags: laravel

```
select u.name,GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT c.category_name SEPARATOR ',') AS category_name FROM users as u 
INNER JOIN category as c ON FIND_IN_SET(c.id, u.cate) 
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: please show your efforts what you have tried till now ?

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: Because laravel is new for me.

Comment: but show us what you have tried

Comment: This upper query convert in laravel. how to write in laravel that's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 User::with('category'=>function($q){
     $q->select( DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT c.category_name SEPARATOR ',') AS category_name"))->whereRaw("find_in_set(c.id, user.cate)")
    })->groupBy("user.id")->get();
```

or you can simply use for any query you have

```
DB::select( DB::raw("select u.name,GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT c.category_name SEPARATOR ',') AS category_name FROM users as u 
INNER JOIN category as c ON FIND_IN_SET(c.id, u.cate) 
GROUP BY u.id));
```

Comment: Consider using `with` it's only valid if you have relationships created

Answer (score 0):

With **query builder** you can do It un this way

```
$data = User::select('users.name')
             ->selectRaw("GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT category.category_name SEPARATOR ',') AS category_name")
             ->join('category', 'category.id', '=', 'users.cate')
             ->groupBy('users.name')
             ->get();
```

Use:

- `selectRaw` for running pure sql queries
- Use `innerJoin` to link two tables
- Use `groupBy` for grouping results this because you're using `GROUP_CONCAT`
- In spite of using table users name i do prefer yo invoke the model name related to It
- Only check in my example table AND column names

Another option use Laravel relationships but for this you will need

- Model for every table
- `belongsTo` and `hasMany` methods created ay your model classes

Also Is neccesary you keep in mind

> You need to `GROUP BY` for every column in your `SELECT` statment because:

- It's part of standar
- Laravel comes with strict mode enabled
- Except MySQL, every SQL engine Will throw an error if you dont do this
- [Here the MySQL docs.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) where you can read more about it, because your `group` is wrong